# What determines if a Juniper router is a route reflector client?

Tags: bgp, juniper, mesh

When I read [bgp router reflector document](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/us/en/software/junos/bgp/topics/topic-map/bgp-rr.html#d321e98__d90057e501):

You see the topology is this:
[image]

You see the Router A B C are in one cluster, D E are not clients of it.
but how to configure to become this?

I compared with the Router B and D:

```
set interfaces fe-0/0/0 unit 2 description to-A
set interfaces fe-0/0/0 unit 2 family inet address 10.10.10.2/30
set interfaces fe-0/0/1 unit 5 description to-C
set interfaces fe-0/0/1 unit 5 family inet address 10.10.10.5/30
set interfaces lo0 unit 2 family inet address 192.163.6.4/32
set protocols bgp group internal-peers type internal
set protocols bgp group internal-peers local-address 192.163.6.4
set protocols bgp group internal-peers export send-ospf
set protocols bgp group internal-peers neighbor 192.168.6.5
set protocols ospf area 0.0.0.0 interface lo0.2 passive
set protocols ospf area 0.0.0.0 interface fe-0/0/0.2
set protocols ospf area 0.0.0.0 interface fe-0/0/1.5
set policy-options policy-statement send-ospf term 2 from protocol ospf
set policy-options policy-statement send-ospf term 2 then accept
set routing-options router-id 192.163.6.4
set routing-options autonomous-system 17
```

```
set interfaces fe-0/0/0 unit 4 description to-A
set interfaces fe-0/0/0 unit 4 family inet address 10.10.10.10/30
set interfaces fe-0/0/1 unit 7 description to-E
set interfaces fe-0/0/1 unit 7 family inet address 10.10.10.13/30
set interfaces lo0 unit 4 family inet address 192.168.0.1/32
set protocols bgp group internal-peers type internal
set protocols bgp group internal-peers local-address 192.168.0.1
set protocols bgp group internal-peers export send-ospf
set protocols bgp group internal-peers neighbor 192.168.6.5
set protocols bgp group internal-peers neighbor 192.168.5.5
set protocols ospf area 0.0.0.0 interface lo0.4 passive
set protocols ospf area 0.0.0.0 interface fe-0/0/0.4
set protocols ospf area 0.0.0.0 interface fe-0/0/1.7
set policy-options policy-statement send-ospf term 2 from protocol ospf
set policy-options policy-statement send-ospf term 2 then accept
set routing-options router-id 192.168.0.1
set routing-options autonomous-system 17
```

this is no difference between them. so, why it formed the upper topology cluster?
I mean, if router B want to become client of Cluster, it shouldn't configure more information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's right there above the diagram:

> Device D and Device E are considered to be nonclients because they have explicitly configured peer relationships with each other. To make them RRroute reflector clients, remove the neighbor 192.168.5.5 statement from the configuration on Device D, and remove the neighbor 192.168.0.1 statement from the configuration on Device E.

In the Cisco world, route reflector clients are defined on the route reflector, not the client.